# how to fix url path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, svn, servlets, bitbucket

I am working for a company and we were using Svn but a week a go we changed to bitbucket and it is also noteworthy that I am working in User interface using eclipse. before changing to bitbucket my jsp files were executed as follow

```
http://localhost:8080/OMIDGUIMaven/index.jsp
```

but after changing to bit bucket we changed the name of the  OMIDGUIMaven folder to OMIDUI so I 
expect to get this Url :

```
http://localhost:8080/OMIDUI/index.jsp
```

but I still get the old url when I run the index.jsp and funny point is that the index.jsp which is in the OMIDUI is executed  so it shows that index.jsp loads properly from the new folder but with the old version of Url

I also in pom.xml file change OMIDGUIMaven to OMIDUI

```
      <build>
    <finalName>OMIDUI</finalName>
</build>
```

Could you please help?should I change anything in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually eclipse does not behave very clever especially in big changes like migrating from svn to git or bitbucket download the latest version of eclipse and try it again